# Side output from all operators in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want all the operators in my Flink program to insert records into a side stream (in addition to the main output stream).  Actually I am looking for something like [side-output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) 
in which it is possible to insert records into the side-stream from all types of operators (including sink and source functions, and not just all types of **process** functions) 
Any idea on how I do that?

Comment: The reason for the need to create stream records from Flink operators (including sources and sinks) is that I want to collect reports from all the Flink operators in my application about their status. This is kind of extended metrics (I considered using Flink Metrics but it is too limited for what I need. Once I have all the metrics from all operators I need to do some processing on them (aggregation etc.), which is very easy to do using Flink. The only problem is that I need to insert these extended metrics records into a stream...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Only the process functions can have general purpose side outputs (windows and CEP do use side outputs, but only in very specific ways).

Can you motivate for us why you want side outputs from sources and sinks? I can see how that could be useful for handling exceptions.

Comment: The reason for the need to create stream records from Flink operators (including sources and sinks) is that I want to collect reports from all the Flink operators in my application about their status. 
This is kind of extended metrics (I considered using Flink Metrics but it is too limited for what I need. 
Once I have all the metrics from all operators I need to do some processing on them (aggregation etc.), which is very easy to do using Flink. The only problem is that I need to insert these extended metrics records into a stream...
(@DavidAnderson)

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, this would require changes to Flink. If you want to pursue the idea, maybe bring it up on the flink-dev mailing list.